# SetTimeOut is stacking all keyup pressed and fires after the timeout has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have set my `setTimeout` to run 1 second after the last `keyup` is typed. I am setting up ajax server side verification.

**Problem**

For some reason, this will wait 1 second and then fire for however many clicks I back before taking a second break. I would like only the last keyup to be triggering the ajax call.

**Code**

```
   form.items = {
        init:function(){
            this.call();
        },
        call:function(){
            //Check all visible elements
            form.init.mainItems.each(function(){
                $(this).keyup(function(){
                    form.items.main($(this));
                });
            });
        },
        main:function(myself){
                    form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer = setTimeout(function(){form.ajaxEvents.call(myself);}, form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimerSetting);
            }
        }
    };

  //Setting up the timer
 form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer = setTimeout(function(){
       form.ajaxEvents.call(myself);
 }, form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimerSetting);

 form.ajaxEvents = {
     ajaxTimerSetting:1000,
     ajaxTimer:null,
     call:function(me){
         clearTimeout(form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer);
         //turn off so we wait for ajax to complete
            $.ajax({
                url:'registration/ajax/'+item,
                data:{"info":me.val()},
                type:'post',
                success:function (data) {
                    //data
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**JsFiddle**

[JS Fiddle for full working code and error described](http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/76Q9v/)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you.

```
var timer;

$("input").on('keyup', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);  //clear any interval on key up
    timer = setTimeout(function() { //then give it a second to see if the user is finished
        //do .post ajax request //then do the ajax call
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You should use [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) with setTimeout()

Comment: `clearInterval` is basically used for stop requesting server when you are writing super fast. Like i am writing 4 letters in a second so it will stop requesting server for one second as mentioned in `setTimeout` and then it will continue, it uses in some optimization work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, when the event `keyup` is fired, you should first verify that there is no existing timeout previously created, otherwise there will be many 1 second timeout fired. If there is already a timeout, you should cancel it using the `clearTimeout(id_timeout)` function. Then you just have to set up your 1 second timeout.

Using your `form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer` to store the information about existing timeout, this will give something like this :

```
main:function(myself){
    // verify if existing timeout
    if(form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer != null) {
        clearTimeout(form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer);
    }
    // finally
    form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer = setTimeout(function(){form.ajaxEvents.call(myself);}, form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimerSetting);
}
```

And probably add a `form.ajaxEvents.ajaxTimer = null` in your triggered function.